# Integrate row information with previous rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to integrate row information with previous rows

```
|      ID      |   no| number |
+--------------+-----+--------+
|       1      |   40|   10   |
|       2      |   32|   12   |
|       3      |   40|   15   |
|       4      |   45|   23   |
|       5      |   32|   15   |
|       6      |   12|   14
|       7      |   40|   20
|       8      |   32|   18
|       9      |   45|   27
|       10     |   12|   16
```

Desired result :

```
|      ID      | no  | number | last number
+--------------+-----+--------+-------------
|       1      |  40 |   10   |     0
|       3      |  32 |   12   |     0
|       3      |  40 |   15   |     0
|       4      |  45 |   23   |     0
|       5      |  32 |   15   |    12
|       6      |  12 |   14   |     0
|       7      |  40 |   20   |    15
|       8      |  32 |   18   |    15
|       9      |  45 |   27   |    23
|      10      |  12 |   16   |    14
```

Comment: I do not understand what you expect.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: And also please explain why last number for 1,2,3,4 is 0? and why 12 for 5?

Comment: Your question is simply unclear, no one can gives you a good answer based on what you provide unless you edit it and help us to help you.

Comment: what is logic, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The best guess from me is - you are looking for a script as below. But according to the below logic, row with "id = 3" should get 10 as value in the column 'last number'

You can check the [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c69251e6e46808c9a36952acc33c582)

```
SELECT *, 
ISNULL
(
    (
        SELECT number 
        FROM your_table C 
        WHERE C.ID = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(ID) FROM your_table B WHERE B.ID < A.ID AND B.no = A.No
        )
    )
,0) [last number]
FROM your_table A
```

Output is-

```
ID  no  number  last number
1   40  10      0
2   32  12      0
3   40  15      10
4   45  23      0
5   32  15      12
6   12  14      0
7   40  20      15
8   32  18      15
9   45  27      23
10  12  16      14
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help.
May God help you